# Using an array as the 'value' part of a Map

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples

The first part of the code below successfully stores a tuple in the value part of a Map. The second part is my attempt to store an array instead of a tuple. It does not work. What is wrong?

```
object MyClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m1 = Map("fname" -> (1,2), "lname" -> (3,4))
    for ((k,v) <- m1) printf("key: %s, value: %s, 0: %s\n", k, v, v._1)

    var states = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, new Array[Int](3)]()
    val states += ("fname" -> (1,2,3))
    val states += ("lname" -> (4,5,6))
    for ((k,v) <- states) printf("key: %s, value: %s, 0: %s\n", k, v, v._1)         
  }
}
```

Here are the errors I get.

[image: Here are the errors I get]

Once I understand the syntax to do the job, I also want to access individual elements in the array.

Comment: Please do not include images of text. They are difficult to read, and they are impossible for the visually impaired to read. They also can't be indexed or searched. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array[Int]` is a type. `new Array[Int](3)` is a value. When declaring a `Map` you need types, not values: `Map[String,Array[Int]]`

`(1,2,3)` is a tuple (or 3-tuple) but you want an array: `Array(1,2,3)`

`v._1` is the first element of a tuple but you want the first element of an array: `v(0)` or `v.head`

This compiles.

```
var states = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Array[Int]]()
states += ("fname" -> Array(1,2,3))
states += ("lname" -> Array(4,5,6))
for ((k,v) <- states) printf("key: %s, value: %s, 0: %s\n", k, v, v(0))
```